# socket.emit in while loop

Tags: javascript, node.js, socket.io

I am trying to emit some JSON to a server every 1 second.

```
while (i > 1) {
    var checkData = setInterval (function () {
        var db = new sqlite3.Database('hud_db_master.sqlite3');
        db.all("SELECT * FROM hud ORDER BY col_id DESC LIMIT 1;", function(err, rows) {
            console.log(rows);
            var jsonData = JSON.stringify(rows);
            socket.emit('clientMessage', jsonData, 'Pi-Voyager');
        });
    }, 1000);
}
```

I get a blank console for about 20 seconds and then the following error:

`FATAL ERROR: CALL_AND_RETRY_LAST Allocation failed - process out of memory`

Before messing with setInterval I was able to successfully emit the data once upon execution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You call `while (i > 1) {` at the beginning but never bring it below 1 which puts it into an infinite loop that will run until out of memory

If you remove the `while` loop, you should still successfully achieve the intended result from what I assume from your intentions

EDIT:

Also, your db doesn't make sense as you create a new one EVERY second. Move the call to `db` creation OUTSIDE of the loop

Comment: Pausing every second.

Comment: @sails4life, yes, since you already use `setInterval`, it will automatically run every second. If you want another function to stop the interval, you can use `clearInterval()`